# How to change the color of selected item ReactJS

Tags: react-native

I have a map function on my app:

```
list.map((item, index) => {
    return (
       <View key={index}>
           <Text 
               style={ this.state.active ? listStyle.listDone : listStyle.list } onPress={() => this.changeStatus(index)}
           > 
               {item} 
           </Text>
       </View>
    )
})
```

I want to change the color when the current item `i` is clicked.

Comment: what is "changeStatus" function? maybe you mean "setState" function?

Comment: no what i mean is how can i change the color of item i clicked ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to select multiple items so instead of controlling the elements using single state value, use an array.

Store the selected indexes in the state array, whenever user click on any new item put it's index in that array otherwise remove it, and during ui creation check whether index in present in array or not and on the basis of that specify the color.

> How to add or remove elements from array?

For that you need to pass a extra parameter in onClick function "the index of item" and by using that index add/remove elements.

**Step1:**

```
Define indexes = [] in state;
```

**Step2:**

```
list.map((item, index) => {
    return (
        <View key={index}>
           <Text 
               style={ this.state.indexes[index] ? listStyle.listDone : listStyle.list } 
               onPress={() => this.changeStatus(index)}> {item} </Text>
        </View>
    )
})

onclick(index) {
    let indexes = this.state.indexes.slice(0);
    if(indexes.indexOf(index) == -1)
        indexes.push(index);
    else{
        let id = indexes.indexOf(index);
        indexes.splice(id, 1)
    }
    this.setState({indexes});
}
```

See this sample working `jsfiddle`: https://jsfiddle.net/mayankshukla5031/17h4Lz5u/

Comment: hi thanks for this but what if i have to select multiple text?

Comment: u didn't tell that u want to select more than one element, updated the ans and `jsfiddle` check again. I don't know Native, check the logic same thing u can write in native. Let me know if it works.

Comment: thanks for this i will try this for refference thanks